# Cannot resolve symbol 'HmsMessageService' in android stuido

Tags: android, android-studio, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I am trying to implement push notifications for Huawei.

For that I am following this toturial:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/codelab/HMSPushKit/index.html#7

But on step 8, when I implement this:

```
public class MyPushService extends HmsMessageService {
private static final String TAG = "PushDemoLog";
@Override
public void onNewToken(String token) {
    super.onNewToken(token);
    Log.i(TAG, "receive token:" + token);
}
```

}

I get this error on HmsMessageService.

> Cannot resolve symbol 'HmsMessageService'

I have added all dependencies as referred in the article. Have installed the hmstoolkitsdk-tool,5.2.0.3000.

This are my Build gradle dependencies:
[image]

How can i resolve this error?

Thanks

Comment: Show, please, contents of `build.gradle (module app)`

Comment: You have dependency, so it should work) Maybe you didn't apply plugin, or didn't add urls in project build.gradle? Or didn't add agconnect-services.json? Could you, please, show **full** content of both build.gradle files as text, not screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is Huawei Push demo, You are advised to follow the README.md step by step : https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-push-clientdemo-android

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.huawei.hms:push:6.7.0.300'
}
```